# jQuery UI autocomplete - problems accessing id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using this: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

I'm initializing a text box like this (partial code):

```
$('#foo').autocomplete
{
     source: function()
     {
          // How to get the id of the element?
     }
}
```

In the `source` callback, I need to know what the id is of the current element. In this example, it's obviously `foo`; in the real application, the selector is dynamically assigned so I don't know what the `id` is.

I looked at the following:

```
console.debug($(this)); // displays [a.widget.a]
console.debug($(this.id)); // displays []
console.debug($(this).attr('id')); // displays undefined
```

**How to get the id of the element?**

Comment: A valid `id` can't start with a number.

Comment: Oops, you are right. I'll fix my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than assigning variables names to all the inputs you want `autocomplete` on, you can use:

```
$('#some_id').autocomplete {
  source: function() {
    var element = this.element[0];
    var element_id = this.element[0].id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, don't forget to favourite!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use...

```
var element = $('#one');

element.autocomplete
{
     source: function()
     {
          var id = element.id;
     }
}
```

Comment: Alex, could I not get it inside `source`? By the way, my selector is something like this: `'#1, #2'` (multiple selectors).

Comment: @StackOverlowNewbie: If it's not in `this.id`, then do a `console.log(this, arguments)` and see what is available to you.